# WPF Radio Button Group Collision with Custom User Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radio-button

I instanciate the same UserControl twice. Both have Radiobuttons and share the GroupName. When I select one all others deselect even when they are part of a different UserControl Instance.

How can this GroupName Collision be avoided?

Here is a minimal example to illustrate the point:

Main xaml

```
<Window x:Class="RadioDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <UserControl x:Name="First"/>
        <UserControl x:Name="Second"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Main Codebehind

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    First.Content = new MyRadio();
    Second.Content = new MyRadio();
}
```

MyRadio xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="RadioDemo.MyRadio"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton GroupName="G" x:Name="RadioOne" Content="RadioOne"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName="G" x:Name="RadioTwo" Content="RadioTwo"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I realize I'm commenting on a really old question that has an accepted answer, but do you even need the GroupName assignment? The RadioButtons should already be logically grouped by their container (StackPanel) in this case. The RadioButtons in a second instance of the user control should already have their own separate logical grouping in their own StackPanel. From my understanding, the only time you really need the GroupName is when you have RadioButtons in the same container, but want to group them separately.

Comment: @nedmech fair point. I do not have a setup to test this but if your radio buttons in the same stackpanel deselect like you want them to there may be no need for an explicit group. - I vaguely remember this being related to a UI library we were forced to use that had implementation gems which lead to workarounds and hacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create group name value dynamically once user control is loaded.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding GroupNameValue}" x:Name="RadioOne" Content="RadioOne"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding GroupNameValue}" x:Name="RadioTwo" Content="RadioTwo"/>
</StackPanel>
```

View-model:

```
private string groupNameValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

public string GroupNameValue
{
    protected get { return this.groupNameValue; }
    set
    {
        this.SetProperty(ref this.groupNameValue, value);
    }
}
```

Where `SetProperty` is implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
Here I used [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) as guarantee of the uniqueness, but you can use whether you want.

With C# 6.0 code can be simplified:

```
private string groupNameValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

public string GroupNameValue => this.groupNameValue;
```

Comment: Clean solution, another approach would be to declare a dependency propertery on the UserControl to hold the GroupName. Like that you could still attach the same GroupName to several UC's when needed.